# Ajax call for get data using laravel and routes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, routes

I have a experience with ajax call with core PHP. Now I want in laravel framework.So its difficult to implement. Actually I have the source in route of

```
"source: "{{route('client.details')}}","
```

I want to put this route in url, but how I dont knw. I tried like below,

```
$.ajax({
method: 'GET', 
url: '/client/details'
success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
$('#invoiceNo').val(response.item.invoiceNo);
$('#DueDate').val(response.item.DueDate); 
}
});
```

controller code

```
public function search2(Request $request)
{ 
$s= Input::get('term');
$clients = Invoice::select("invoiceNo" ,"Total", "invoiceDate", "DueDate" )->where('status',['sent,Partially paid'])->where('client_id',$request->id)->get();
if(count($clients) == 0){
$searchResult[] = "No Item found";
}
else{
foreach ($clients as $key => $value) {//fill here too
$searchResult[] = ['invoiceNo' => $value->invoiceNo, 'Total' => $value->Total , 'invoiceDate' => $value->invoiceDate , 'DueDate' => $value->DueDate];
}
} 
return $searchResult; 
}
```

and my route is

```
Route::get('/client/search/details', 'ClientsController@search2')->name('client.details');
```

I dont know what is the issue. Im getting error in ajax url part. Can anyone suggest me what is the solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you are suppose to return a response instance, not an array from a controller method. Try `return response()->json($searchResult);` instead of `return $searchResult;`

Answer (score 0):

AJAX works on client side and therefore it has no knowledge of your named routes. The named routes work on server side, inside Laravel.

You have to tell AJAX to get the full URL:

`$.ajax({
method: 'GET', 
url: '/client/search/details'
...`

Answer (score 0):

Replace **url: '/client/details'**  by **url: "{{route('client.details')}}",**

Then complete code be look like this in ajax section:-

```
method: 'GET', 
url: "{{route('client.details')}}",
success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
$('#invoiceNo').val(response.item.invoiceNo);
$('#DueDate').val(response.item.DueDate); 
}
});
```